# let S be a nonempty subset of R that is bounded below.prove that Inf S=-Sup {-s: s∈ S}

Tags: real-analysis

given that s is bounded below then ∃ t ∈ R such for all s ∈ S ,such that t≤s (1).then let suppose Inf S=t

If S is bounded below then the nonempty set S={-s, s∈ S} is bounded above.then -s ≥ t(2).

But in (1) we have t≤s.if we put negate this then -s≤t which is opposite of (2).

therefore Inf S=-Sup {-s: s∈ S}.

does it even make sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [How to prove $\inf(S)=-\sup(-S)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488022/infs-sup-s?rq=1), please. And make sure you learn how to write a question. It was very hard to read.

Comment: ok so does my poof make sense ?