# Proving $\inf F = - \sup E$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, supremum-and-infimum

Assume $ E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is nonempty and bounded above. Define $F:\{-x:x\in E\}$. Prove that F is nonempty and bounded below and that $\inf F = - \sup E$.

Here's my rough proof:

F is nonempty because $-1 \in F$. I know for bounded below we need $ \exists \beta \in E$ such that $ x \geq \beta \  \forall X \in F$.

Other than this I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be much appreciated!

I understand there have been similar arguments made for proving inf(A)=-sup(-A), but I'm very confused now because it seems like I need to prove inf(-A)=-sup(A)

Comment: It looks $F=E$, according to your notation. Can you check again what $F$ is?

Comment: @choco_addicted I apologize. F is supposed to be -x such that x is in E. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: My pleasure. In your proof, $-1\in F$ is not appropriate, because we don't know whether $1\in E$ is true. I hope [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488022/how-to-prove-infs-sup-s?rq=1) help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sup E \geq x$ for every $x \in E$, then $-\sup E \leq -x$ for every $x \in  E$. This proves $-\sup E$ is a lower bound of $F$, i.e. $- \sup E \leq \inf F$. I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm guessing it would be easy to let X in the RHS and show it is a subset of the LHS and vice versa? Or should I try to prove $inf F \geq -sup E$?

Comment: Suppose $-\sup E < \inf F$, for contradiction. Then $\sup E > -\inf F$. Now use a similar argument to the one above to conclude that $-\inf F$ is an upper bound of $E$. This is a contradiction, why? Thus we are left with $\inf F = - \sup E$, which was desired.

Comment: @Nikitau Tell me if you are stuck, and I can give further hints.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to understand. $ - inf F$ cannot be an upper bound of E, because by definition it is supposed to be the greatest lower bound? I appreciate your patience!

Comment: Almost. We assumed that $-\sup E < \inf F$, which also gives us $\sup E > - \inf F$. $-\inf F < \sup E$ AND $-\inf F$ is an upper bound (this you have to show, of course) implies that there is an upper bound smaller then $\sup E$, i.e. $\sup E$ is not the least upper bound. Then our assumption that $-\sup E < \inf F$ is incorrect. What I am stressing is that $-\inf F$ can very well be an upper bound, but not an upper bound less than $\sup E$, since the supremum is the smallest of such.

Comment: OH. How silly of me. Thank you so much!! I did manage to prove that -inf F is an upper bound. Quick side question, could I say that F is nonempty because E is non-empty and F is defined as -x for x in E?

Comment: Good job! This type of question is a matter of letting the definitions do the work. Yes that is correct, we are allowed to assume that there is an $x \in E$ (non-empty), so $-x$ is then an element of $F$. To be unnecessarily precise, we are also using the fact that the real numbers have additive inverses, i.e. for every $x$ there is a $-x$ in the reals.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help! I really appreciate it :)